# React: window.close() working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox, browser, frontend

I have a single-page react app hosted on github pages, which comes with many limitations. In order to get my "Login with Twitter" flow working, I found it was necessary to open the dynamic twitter login url in a new tab, give the Twitter API an endpoint on my *backend* as the callback URL, and then have my backend redirect the user to the root url of my frontend client with the generated JWT token in the URL as a query (`/?token=abcd1234`). I then have some code on the landing page of my client that looks like this:

```js
useEffect(() => {

        // at /?close, just close the window
        if (props.location.search === '?close') {
            window.close()
            closeWindow()
            setShowCloseMessage(true)

        // at /?token, save the token to localstorage, then close the window
        } else if (tokenUrlRE.test(props.location.search)) {
            const token = props.location.search.match(tokenRE)[0]
            localStorage.setItem('token', token)
            window.close()
            closeWindow()
            setShowCloseMessage(true)
        }

    }, [])
```

This works fine in Chrome, but not Firefox - perhaps Firefox is more stringent about requiring that Windows only be closed by the script that opened them, and Chrome allows any script on the same *domain* that opened a window to close it?

Anyway, several other answers here on Stackexchange recommended the following code, which I added inside the `closeWindow()` function appearing in the above code:

```js
function closeWindow() {
            console.log('clicked close')
            window.open('', '_parent', '')
            window.close()
        }
```

But this also did not work in Firefox.
Furthermore, this additional solution I found caused React to crash:

`open(location, '_self').close()`

Is there any way to accomplish what I want with Firefox? For the time being I have simply used that `showClose` state variable seen in the first code block to display a "Sign-in successful, please return to the previous tab" message, but this is less than ideal.

Comment: Well an answer would still be interesting, but I solved the problem with a different approach, instead of opening a new tab redirecting to the homepage, saving credentials, then closing the tab, I open the twitter login in the same tab, redirect to the homepage, save the credentials, then push the user to the correct route with useHistory()